# grpc and protobuf with variable keys

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a hash of key values pairs.

I do not have the keys, nor the values.

I can assume most will be there, but sometimes keys are removed and others are added. Is there any way for me to have a message with variable keys?

```
{
  "knownkey1": "value",
  "knownkey2": {
    "unknown-key1": "value",
    "unknown-key2": "value"
  }
}
```

or is the best ways  to just serialize it using json stringify in the message? i would think that would defeat the whole purpose of using grpc.

```
message Rate {
  string ticker = 1;
  string value = 2;
}

message GetAllResponse {
  string lastUpdated = 1;
  repeated Rate payload = 2;
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far for a proto Message that tries to model this?

Comment: Nothing that works, i've been converting the key value pair to a repeatable type of objects updated above

Comment: ah! just found the maps type: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can just use the maps type as outlined here: 
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

Comment: Ah - yes.  Sorry - I wasn't understanding what you were looking for.  Interestingly enough - [maps are represented as repeated pairs over the wire](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#backwards-compatibility) for backward compatibility.